# Using Osmosis to extract highways and move to a MySQL database

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

I am pretty new to using Osmosis and I have been having a hard time of getting it going. So basically I am trying to extract highway data from the latest osm planet dump file using osmosis and moving into a mysql database.

I followed the simple script of

```
osmosis --read-pbf file="C:\A\Osmosis\planet.pbf" --tf accept-ways highways=* --used-node --write-xml highways
```

But I keep getting the error 
"the following named pipes () and 1 default pipes have not been terminated with appropriate output sinks."

Can anyone help me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to try your osmosis based filtering with a **smaller** country extract first. See [Planet.osm](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) wiki page for sources about raw OSM data, especially geofabrik.de
Because processing the whole planet.pbf file can cause errors related to disc space or RAM.

But I cannot give you a concrete solution about your error message from osmosis, sorry.

As an alternative to osmosis, you can try [osmfilter](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter) in connection with osmconvert.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one
[Import OSM file to MYSQL](https://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=9870)

Another alternative is to use  goal / ogr2ogr tool with OSM Shape file as following (I am on Mac OS)

```
$ brew install  gdal --with-mysql

$ mysql -e "set global max_allowed_packet = 16777216*10; set global default_storage_engine = MyISAM; "

$ogr2ogr -overwrite -progress -f "MySQL" MYSQL:zcta,user=root PATH_TO_OSM_SHAPE_FILE.shp
```